# Scale invariant definition of the Sobolev norm $\|\|_{m,\Omega}$ for $H^m(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I learned the following from Constantin and Foias's Navier-Stokes Equations (Chapter 4):

> We say that a function of a bounded open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $c(\Omega)$, is scale invariant if $c(\Omega)=c(\Omega')$ for all $\Omega'$ obtained from $\Omega$ by a rigid transformation and a dilation $x\mapsto\delta x$.
>
> Denote by $T_\delta$ the operation mapping functions defined on $\Omega$ to function defined on $\Omega_\delta:=\{\delta x\mid x\in\Omega\}$:
>   $$
> (T_\delta f)(y)=f(\frac{y}{\delta}). 
> $$
>   When we refer to the way something scales we mean under the dilations $\delta$ and operations $T_\delta$. One can  modify the definition of the norms $\|\cdot\|_{m,\Omega}$ of $H^m(\Omega)$ in such a way that they scale as the pure $m$-th order derivatives do.   We shall denote by 
>   $
> |\Omega|=\int_\Omega 1\ dx
> $
>   and by
>   $
> L(\Omega)=L=|\Omega|^{1/n}
> $
>   the linear size of $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Define $\|\|_{m,\Omega}$ with
>   $$
> \|f\|_{m,\Omega}^2=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2(|\alpha|-m)}{n}}}
> \int_{\Omega}|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx
> $$
>   With this definition the quantity $\|f\|_{m,\Omega}$ scales like $L^{\frac{n}{2}-m}$, i.e.,
>   $$
> C(\Omega):=\dfrac{1}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{m}{n}}}\cdot \|f\|_{m,\Omega}
> $$
>   is scale invariant.

Here are my questions:

- Would anybody find a heuristic way to cook up the exponent in the term
  $$
  \displaystyle \color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2(|\alpha|-m)}{n}}}?
  $$
- A direct simplification gives
  $$
  C(\Omega)=\sqrt{\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} \big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2|\alpha|}{n}-1}\int_\Omega|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx}.
  $$
  Would anybody show me why this is scale invariant?

Comment: One can use [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis). We have $[{\rm d}x] \equiv [\prod_{i=1}^n{\rm d}x_i] = L^n$ and $[D^\alpha] = L^{-\alpha}$ thus $[\Omega^{\frac{2\alpha-2m}{n}}\int |D^\alpha f|^2{\rm d}x] = L^{2\alpha-2m}L^{n-2\alpha} = L^{n-2m} = \Omega^{1-\frac{2m}{n}}$. For your last expression we see that the terms in $C(\Omega)$ has dimension $\Omega^{\frac{2\alpha}{n}-1} \cdot \Omega \cdot \Omega^{-\frac{2\alpha}{n}} = 1$.

Comment: @Winther, Thanks for your comment. I don't quite understand why $[D^\alpha]=L^{-\alpha}$.  Would you elaborate? Besides, do you have a reference for your analysis? (I'm interested in how one might turn your analysis in a mathematically rigorous statement.)

Comment: I'm assuming $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ so the "units" of $D$ is the inverse units of $x$ (which we take as having unit of "length" $L$) thus $D^\alpha$ has units $\frac{1}{L^\alpha}$. I don't know this subject very good (as to elaborate) so take this with a grain of salt. What I'm mentioning above is just a standard way of deriving the "units" of a formula and in this language scale-invariance can be though of as the formula "being dimensionless" (well it's a nessesary condition for this to be true).

Comment: @Winther: This looks like a very interesting heuristic argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related question

[Scalar property of $ C(\Omega)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2|\alpha|-n}{n}}} \int_{\Omega}|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1796147/9464)

and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1803486/9464) gives a direct answer for the second question.

For the first question, one can use the calculation of $\|T_\delta f\|_{m,\delta\Omega}$ to find the correct exponents.

Answer (score 2):

The following  is an [answer](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/#comment-468823) by Terry Tao, which is similar to Winther's comment.

> If $f$ is dimensionless, then $D^\alpha f$ has the units of $L^{-|\alpha|}$, and so $\int_\Omega |D^\alpha f|^2\ dx$ has the units of $L^n \times (L^{-\alpha})^2$. As $\Omega$ has units of $L^n$, each summand in $\|f\|_{m,\Omega}^2$ has the units of $(L^n)^{\frac{2(|\alpha|-m)}{n}} \times L^n \times (L^{-\alpha})^2 = L^{n-2m}$, and hence $\|f\|_{m,\Omega}$ scales as $L^{\frac{n}{2}-m}$ as claimed.