# Scalar property of $ C(\Omega)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\frac{2|\alpha|-n}{n}}} \int_{\Omega}|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces

This is closely related to a previous question:
[Scale invariant definition of the Sobolev norm $\|\|_{m,\Omega}$ for $H^m(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790894/9464)

This question focuses on the direct calculation (by change of variables) of the simplest one-dimensional case.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty bounded open set. Denote the Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$ as $|\Omega|$. For $f\in H^m(\Omega)$, define

$$
\|f\|_{m,\Omega}^2=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2(|\alpha|-m)}{n}}}
\int_{\Omega}|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx.
$$
According the so-called "dimensional analysis" (see the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790894/scale-invariant-definition-of-the-sobolev-norm-m-omega-for-hm-omega#comment3655721_1790894) to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790894/9464)), the quantity

$$
C(\Omega):=\dfrac{1}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{n-2m}{n}}}\cdot \|f\|_{m,\Omega}^2
$$
is scale invariant, namely, $C(\Omega)=C(\delta\Omega)$ for any $\delta>0$ where
$$
\delta\Omega:=\{\delta x\mid x\in \Omega\}.
$$

Note that we can rewrite $C(\Omega)$ as
$$
C(\Omega)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}\color{blue}{\big|\Omega\big|^{\dfrac{2|\alpha|-n}{n}}}
\int_{\Omega}|D^\alpha f|^2\ dx \tag{*}
$$

I would like test the statement above by a direct calculation of $C(\delta\Omega)$ using change of variables with the simple case $n=1$ and $\Omega=(0,1)$. In this case, $(*)$ becomes
$$
C(\delta\Omega)=\sum_{k\leq m}\color{blue}{\delta^{2k-1}}
\int_{\delta\Omega}|D^kf(x)|^2\ dx.
$$
To show $C(\Omega)=C(\delta\Omega)$, it suffices to show that
$$
\int_0^\delta|D^k f|^2\ dx=\delta^{1-2k}\int_0^1|D^k f(x)|^2\ dx.
$$

But even in the case $k=1$, one can check that the identity
$$
\int_0^\delta |f'(x)|^2\ dx=\frac{1}{\delta}\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2\ dx
$$ is wrong.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the calculation of $C(\delta\Omega)$, when the domain changes from $\Omega$ to $\delta\Omega$, $f$ should changes to be $T_\delta f$ where
$$
T_\delta f(y):=f(\frac{y}{\delta}),\quad y\in\delta\Omega.
$$
It does not make sense at all to compare 
$\|f\|_{m,\Omega}$ with $\|f\|_{m,\delta\Omega}$ since if $f$ is defined on $\Omega$, it is not necessarily defined on $\delta\Omega$.

Instead, one should compare $\|f\|_{m,\Omega}$ with $\|T_\delta f\|_{m,\delta\Omega}$. Then everything makes sense with the change of variable formula. For instance, in the last identity in OP, one would instead get
$$
\int_0^\delta |(T_\delta f)'(x)|^2\ dx=\frac{1}{\delta}\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2\ dx\tag{1}
$$
Noting that by chain rules
$$
(T_\delta f)'(x)=\frac{1}{\delta}f'(\frac{x}{\delta})
$$
we can check by change of variables that (1) is indeed true.